# Firebase Database search query issue

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a search feature where users can search other registered. i managed to get the search to work but its not giving the desired result. No matter what keyword i input, it brings up all the registered users on the search result instead of just the ones related to the keyword.

i'm no expert in java but ive tried changing and rearranging some lines, but the outcome is still the same.

```
private void SearchPeopleAndFriends(String searchBoxInput)
{
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<FindFriends> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<FindFriends>().
            setQuery(UsersRef, FindFriends.class).build(); //query build past the query to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FindFriends, FindFriendsActivity.FindFriendViewHolder> adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FindFriends, FindFriendViewHolder>(options)
    {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FindFriendsActivity.FindFriendViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull FindFriends model)
        {
            holder.username.setText(model.getFullname());
            holder.status.setText(model.getStatus());
            Picasso.get().load(model.getProfileimage()).into(holder.profileimage);

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent findOthersIntent = new Intent(FindFriendsActivity.this, FindFriendsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(findOthersIntent);

                }
            });
        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public FindFriendsActivity.FindFriendViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
        {
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.all_user_display_layout,viewGroup,false);

            FindFriendsActivity.FindFriendViewHolder viewHolder=new FindFriendsActivity.FindFriendViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }
    };

    SearchResultList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}

public class FindFriendViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView username, status;
    CircleImageView profileimage;

    public FindFriendViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_user_profile_name);
        status = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_user_status);
        profileimage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_user_profile_pic);
    }
}
```

Instead of it bringing user related to the keyword in the search result, it brings up all the users in the database. my goal is for it to only display whatever users name contains the keyword that was inputed

This is my model class

```
public class FindFriends {

    public String profileimage, fullname, status;

    public FindFriends()
    {

    }

    public String getProfileimage() {
        return profileimage;
    }

    public void setProfileimage(String profileimage) {
        this.profileimage = profileimage;
    }

    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public FindFriends(String profileimage, String fullname, String status) {
        this.profileimage = profileimage;
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

My Firebase Refs:

```
 mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you build `UsersRef`, and how you turn it into a query.

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: There is no search here `UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");` If you want to filter/order data, you'll have to implement a Firebase query. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Comment: Provide us an example of the constrait that you want to use. What is the expected result? Please also responde with @AlexMamo